# Django forms don't get up-to-date from db

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have form where I print all of records from table(lets say its 'item' table in database). User can add new items to db using ajax. Data saves to db correct but when I refresh page i don't see new tags in my multi select box.

I thought cache is a problem but it doesn't.

So I have question: Where is a problem that I can see add records correct but when i refresh this same page where every time select all rows from table then i don't see these new records?

I'm using sqlite and it's development server.

**Forms.py:**

```
BLANK_CHOICE = (('', '---------'),)

class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tag_from = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label='Tags', choices=OrderItemList.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name'))
    tag_to = forms.MultipleChoiceField()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('price', 'client', 'platform')

    def __init__(self, request_client_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['platform'].choices = BLANK_CHOICE + tuple(
            Platform.objects.filter(client_id=request_client_id).values_list('id', 'name'))
```

**View.py:**

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff, login_url='/account/login/')
def order_create(request, request_client_id):
    dict = {}

    dict['form_order'] = OrderCreateForm(request_client_id)
    return render(request, 'panel/order/form.html', dict)
```

Comment: You should show the code for your form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the `tag_from` choices in the field definition, so the choices are evaluated once when the form first loads. You can fix the problem by setting the choices in the `__init__` method instead.

```
class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tag_from = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label='Tags', choices=())
    ...

    def __init__(self, request_client_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['tag_from'].choices = OrderItemList.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name'))
        ...
```

Another option would be to use a [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) instead of a regular multiple choice field. With a model multiple choice field, Django will evaluate the queryset each time the form is initialised.

```
class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tag_from = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label='Tags', queryset=OrderItemList.objects.all())
```